# Form1 hides instead of closing

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple login page on which if i click login button form1 should hide and form2 should popup and on form2 when i click logout it should bring me back to form1, problem is that when i click logout button on form2 it brings me back to form1 like it should but when i click "X" (Close) on form1 it hides (I can see the application running in task manager) instead of closing.

form1 sign in button code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 mainUI = new Form2();
        mainUI.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

form2 logout button code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 loginPage = new Form1();
        loginPage.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You are complaining about Form1 hiding instead of closing, yet you have `this.Close();` in your Form1 code?

Comment: this (in this.Close) is referring to form2, not form1. Did you mean this.Hide?

Comment: @IanH. what are you saying? I think you meant this.Hide(); in my Form1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here, you are creating a new instance of Form1 instead of opening it again:

```
Form1 loginPage = new Form1();
```

Here try this one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formToBeOpen = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
    formToBeOpen.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Now regarding your post, that if you close your Form2, your Form1 is still running on the background, because of this code:

```
this.Hide();
```

You just hide it, then open your Form2, then you click the <kbd>X</kbd> button on your Form2 which closes your Form2 but not necessarily mean will close your Form1 as well, since it's still running on the background. If you want to close your Form1, add this on your Form2 code:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    var formToBeOpen = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
    formToBeOpen.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yeah thank you very much it works like charm, btw can you please explain what this code is doing ( I mean that SingleOrDefault(); part)

Comment: As I have said, Form1 loginPage = new Form1(); creates a new instance of Form1. So in order to open your hiding form, you need to use Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault(); which calls your running Form1 which is hidden on the background. @DanialAhmed

Comment: could you explain / elaborate, why OP sees " the application running in task manager" after he has closed `Form1` ? that would really boost your post

Comment: Nice answer: Gives a solution which works, and explains comprehensively why the problem arose in the first place. +1. May be you could add that it is still running in the background, because he is closing the second instance of `Form1` and not the original one that is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to answer. because you declare a new instance in button logout. in form1 button put this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 x = new Form2(this);            
    x.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

as form2, since i pass form1, put this code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form form1;
    public Form2(Form x)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = x;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        form1.Show();
    }
}
```